# NodeJS and MySQL, dealing with rows

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am beginner with NodeJS and I am currently using the node, express, and mysql packages. I'm trying to check whether the person is already registered or not.

If so, the following code should be executed:

```
    req.session.user = user;
    req.flash('success_notification', 'You are logged in');
    console.log("creating session :" ,req.session.user);
```

However, `authenticated` always remains 'false' when I try to check if it was set to true.

```
 if (authenticated === true)
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

This is my code to handle login attempts:

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    var user = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var authenticated = false;

    var query = "Select * from  user where username = \'" + user + "\'" + " AND pw = \'" + password  + "\'";

    connection.query(query, function (err,rows,fields) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else if (rows.length) {
            authenticated = true;
            console.log(authenticated);
        }
        else {
            console.log('False Password or Username');
        }
    });

    console.log(authenticated);
    if (authenticated === true) {
        req.session.user = user;
        req.flash('success_notification', 'You are logged in');
        console.log("creating session :" ,req.session.user);
    }

    res.redirect('/');    
});
```

Comment: What is your current output?  Also, you should use prepared statements to build your query.

Comment: My current output is at first 'false' and then 'true'. However, before 'true' appears it seems to me that redirect is executed before.

Comment: As a note, it seems that you're storing the user's password in the database in plaintext. This is [really, really bad](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/120540/136144), and as @TimBiegeleisen alludes to, your query is currently vulnerable to SQL injection. For example, someone could pass a carefully-crafted username into the code and have the ability to run queries on your database.

Comment: @ChrisForrence On the bright side, these vulnerabilites will lead to more SO questions being opened, and hence more points for us :-)

Comment: I am aware of the risks and I also intend to use the '+connection.escape()' option to prevent SQL injections and bcrypt to hash one´s password. However, before doing so I wanted to test if my code even works with a sample database and hard-coded user password and username. But obviously it doesn´t and I can´t figure out the reason...

Comment: *Disclaimer: this is my first time looking at database queries in node.js* Because node.js is asynchronous in nature, your code will continue running while `connection.query(...)` is still going. That's why `authenticated` is still false. To fix this, I'd set session information and redirect inside of a callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes for a callback issue.

I had the same problem.

The condition `if (authenticated === true)` gets validated before your query is completed and has returned so `authenticated`becomes `true` only after it validates itself.

The way you can have it to work for any kind of boolean query returns is to include it within your query of to create a callback function.

So if you encapsulate your condition within your query, it should be working fine.

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    var user = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    //var authenticated = false;

    var query = "Select * from  user where username = \'" + user + "\'" + " AND pw = \'" + password  + "\'";

    connection.query(query, function (err,rows,fields) {

        var authenticated = false; //Encapsulate your authenticated variable since you won't need it outside this scope

        if (err) console.log(err);
        else if (rows.length) {
            authenticated = true;
            console.log(authenticated);
        }
        else {
            console.log('False Password or Username');
        }

        /** Moved here */
        console.log(authenticated);
        if (authenticated === true) {
            req.session.user = user;
            req.flash('success_notification', 'You are logged in');
            console.log("creating session :" ,req.session.user);
        }

        res.redirect('/');

    });

    // Moved wihin the your query
    /*
    console.log(authenticated);
    if (authenticated === true) {
        req.session.user = user;
        req.flash('success_notification', 'You are logged in');
        console.log("creating session :" ,req.session.user);
    }

    res.redirect('/');
    */

});
```